# How to write a cross-platform npm wrapper package and circumvent EBADPLATFORM error upon unneeded "conditional dependency" installation?

Tags: node.js, npm, cross-platform

Let's say I wanted to create a cross-platform `frobnicator` package.

I was lucky and found some npm packages needed, but they're all platform dependent

- `frobnicator-win`
- `frobnicator-mac`
- `frobnicator-linux`

So I only need a cross-platform wrapper. The code could be really pretty simple (assuming API consistency):

```
var frobnicator;
if (process.platform == 'win32') {
  frobnicator = require('frobnicator-win')
} else if (process.platform == 'darwin') {
  frobnicator = require('frobnicator-mac')
} else { // let's assume this will work
  frobnicator = require('frobnicator-linux')
}
// do the thing
```

**Here comes the issue: each of the small modules is a good citizen and declares in an appropriate entry in their `package.json` what are their compatible platforms, respectively:**

`"os": ["win32"]` / `"os": ["darwin"]` / `"os": ["linux"]`

There are two problems here:

1) I depend on modules in a platform-dependent way (I never need all of them, just one), but I have to put them all in my `package.json` (it's not perfect, but we can live with that)

2) It seems actually that depending on a module whose `os` doesn't match current OS is impossible because `npm install` will fail.

Say, I wanted to install a mac package on windows:

```
$ vim package.json
... // added all dependencies

$ npm install
...
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: frobnicator-mac@1.0.0
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: ia32
```

**Is there any way out of the situation other than asking the owners of subpackages to lift the `os` requirements?**

What could be the best workaround to actually check the platform without doing it in `package.json`?
Throwing a runtime exception / calling error callback immediately /  `process.exit(1)` in CLI script at runtime if the platform doesn't match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`optionalDependencies` entry](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html#optionaldependencies) is the way to go.

`npm` will try to install the optional dependency by default, but failing to install it (for instance due to platform restrictions of a module, but not only) will not fail the whole process

Comment: what happens if for some reason all of the optional dependencies fail?

Comment: AFAIU all the optional deps are optional so npm should not complain. I'd have a nullpointer in my code though.